# How can I use Firebase custom auth with an openID provider?

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, steam

I currently have a web project for a game and I want users to be able to login to share stuff, that is currently done (and neatly working) using google's firebase authentication.

But I want people to be able to be authenticated via Steam (using Oauth2)

the firebase reference/API (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) wasn't to helpful as I couldn't find exact (working)  examples of what I need to implement and I don't have too much experience with Oauth2 or Firebase yet.

from http://steamcommunity.com/dev I got my API key and that I should use "http://steamcommunity.com/openid" as the provider.

And I tried using it this way:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider("steamcommunity.com/openid");

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).catch(function(error)
{
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

this is the basic function that works with all the default providers (Google, Twitter, Facebook, etc)

However I get a "provider ID not supported" in the console, and I have obviously forgotten something somewhere, but I don't really know what it is exactly (I know I should be inputting the API secret from steam somewhere) and I am not sure for where to start looking (eg. do I need to change anything in my firebase settings, ..)

It would be really helpful if someone could help me out with my problem or point to a working example that I can go through, as my googling has only led me to the official firebase references and API and those haven't really helped me so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`firebase.auth.OAuthProvider` currently only supports existing providers and has not been extended to support additional providers.
You would need to use custom authentication. I just googled and found this library for authentication with Steam: https://www.npmjs.com/package/steam-login. You can use that to sign in with Steam and then get the Steam user ID, mint a custom token with it using Firebase Admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens using that Steam UID and then send the custom token to the client to complete sign in with `signInWithCustomToken`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth

Comment: if your client never makes use of the firebase SDK to read/write your firebase database, is it ever necessary to mint a custom firebase token? 
Can I just receive an ID token from an IdP client-side, and add it to the header of every one of my custom REST server calls? 
The server can verify the token is valid with the IdP, and then permit read/write via Admin SDK. 
I can also signout of the IdP and the client-side token would no longer be valid.
Is there ever a place I'd get stuck without firebase tokens?

Comment: Yeah you can do that if you are going through admin SDK on your server side.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with Identity Platform provided by GCP. You can find the documentation in the following link. You need to have a billing enabled Firebase project to do so.

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/oidc

First you have to configure the new OpenID Connect provider in GCP console. Then you can simply use Firebase [OAuthProvider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.OAuthProvider) as you usually use with other Firebase provided OAuth services.

I will not going to explain every step here because the documentation has everything you need to know.

Comment: Hi Ramesh,

I am currently just setting this up - The Client ID would be the API key that you get via the steam platform?

Josh

Comment: @Josh90 No, client ID is a different thing. See [this article](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview/oauth)